# can somebody explain this sentence in better words?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, magnetics, ferrite, core

[image]

what is the meaning of "reproducible Al values over time" and why should we need it to be reproducible over time???
and what is "production spread"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text defines Ai as inductance in mH per 1000 turns and that it's only for cores with gapped centre leg.

The sentence confusing you is:

> *"Shimming core halves will not yield reproducible Ai values over time, temperature and production spread."*

The manufacturer wants to mass-produce cores, making large numbers of them.

They want all the cores they make to be identical and stay that way forever. They want them to have the same characteristics and for those characteristics to never change. They can't be - but the goal is to get as close to it as possible.

When they make a core, they want to produce one with the same characteristics as the others. They want to their production line to reproduce those same characteristics in all the cores they make. They want *reproducible* characteristics.

They can't achieve it because the production process, materials and design cannot be perfect. There will be some inaccuracy in each core and their characteristics will vary between each one manufactured. When a quantity are made, the range which they vary by is the *production spread*. If you use shims, the characteristics can change too much and the spread can get too wide.

As a core ages *over time*, its characteristics will change. If you use shims, they can now change too much.

Across the full operating *temperature* range, a core's characteristics will change. If you use shims, they can now change too much.

So what it's saying is...

If you use shimming between the core halves, then you'll get too much variation between the all the cores you make.

The variations across all those cores are caused by (a) inconsistencies in the original manufacturing process, (b) the effects of temperature when operating and (c) the parts changing as they get older.

Answer (score 2):

Shimming is a mechanical engineering term. It means to stick a thin material between two things to separate them.

> What is the meaning of "reproducible Al values over time"?

It means it doesn't changes over the life of the product.

> What is "production spread"?

Production spread is how much a specification varies between individual units when you manufacture a bunch of the same product.

> Why should we need it to be reproducible over time???

Because I need to know what it is I'm buying, what it is that I have, and I want to know that if it is working today it will work the same tomorrow.

Comment: According to your answer it says “shimming doesn't change the Al parameter over the life of the product” so it seems to be an advantage of shimming not a disadvantage. whereas in previous sentence it is talking about inadequacy of shimming. What is my confusion?

Comment: No. I'm directly answering your question "What is the meaning of *reproducible Al values over time*?"

Comment: so it says "shimming does change the Al parameter over the life of the product"?? and what about the mentioned "temperture" term?? thankfully.

Comment: No. I think you might not be understanding me due to second language. I am not telling you what the book is saying. I am answering YOUR question about what does the phrase "reproducible Al values over time mean". As in the phrase "reproducible Al values over time" means that the Al values do not change over the life of the product. Then in your book it says "*Shimming core halves will NOT  yield reproducible Ai values over time.*" which means that shimming core halves will not do whatever the phrase says. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, the second language. Thanks for your patience. So as the conclusion: in Shimming method, Al value will change over time. Is it right? And how about the “temperature” term??

Comment: Yes. Basically what the book is saying is that shimming core halves causes everything to affect and change Ai.